How to create a OneNote notebook in a newly created folder?
I am creating a new folder within an existing one using this little snippet:
public DriveItem createDriveItemFolder(String driveId, String folderId, String name) {
        DriveItem newDriveItem = new DriveItem();
        newDriveItem.additionalDataManager().put("@microsoft.graph.conflictBehavior", new JsonPrimitive("rename"));
        Folder folder = new Folder();
        newDriveItem.folder = folder;
        newDriveItem.name = name;
        DriveItem post = this.getGraphServiceClient().drives(driveId).items(folderId).children().buildRequest().post(newDriveItem);
        return post;
    }

As ou can see, I get the DriveItem directly. Now I need to create a new blank OneNote notebook inside this DriveItem (folder) but I cannot find any suitable method to do this.  I didn't find anything on the web so maybe you have an idea?
